# Iterate through a json object

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my object

```
var myObject = {"HardGood":362,"Music":2};

console.log(myObject[0]); // undefined? instead of "Hardwood 362"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the first element in an object like this: `myObject.key` and your key is `HardGood`.

In arrays it's done like this:

```
var _Array = [];
_Array .push('x1'); //pushing in array
_Array .push('x2');

console.log(_Array[0]); // getting the first element in that array
```

Update: if you want to get it dynamically:

```
    var myObject = {"HardGood":362,"Music":2};

    for(var key in myObject){
      console.log(key +':'+myObject[key]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`myObject` is an object not an array, so using `[0]` will indeed be undefined.
Use `myObject.HardGood` or `myObject.Music` to get the value or that property

**Code**

```
console.log(myObject.HardGood); // will output 362
console.log(myObject.Music); // will output 2
```

**UPDATE**

```
var objects = [
    {
       "title": "HardGood"
       "type": "362"
    },
    {
       "title": "Music"
       "type": "2"
    }
];

console.log(objects[0].title); // output HardGood
console.log(objects[1].type); // output 2
```

Comment: Thankyou, how do I obtain the HardGood & Music? because the object will change and it will be difficult to hardcode all of the different items.

Comment: @Jason view my update with an example that you will understand better

Comment: Hi, I get where you are coming from, but I have no control over the structure of the object, unfortunately it arrives as var myObject = {"HardGood":362,"Music":2}; not as in your example. I am having a brain fade today, so if I am missing something, please let me know, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to access `JSON` object property with `.` Like below

```
var myObject = {"HardGood":362,"Music":2};
console.log(myObject.HardGood); //362
```

**Useful links** Have a look at below links to understand it better.

[Javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

[JS-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation](https://medium.com/@prufrock123/js-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-797c4e34f01d)

[MDN - OperatorsProperty_Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)